# Add bitmap resources to list

Tags: c#, list, bitmap, resources

I'm working on a cardgame and have 52 bitmaps in my resources (all the cards). As it works now when dealing the 2 cards:

```
public void GiveTwoRandomCardsFromCardsList()
    {

        Random random = new Random();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        int slumptal = random.Next(0, 52);
        card1 = Cards[slumptal];

        bool flag = false;

        while (!flag)
        {
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        int slumptal2 = random.Next(0, 52);

        if (slumptal != slumptal2)
        {
            card2 = Cards[slumptal2];
            flag = true;
        }

        }

    }
```

What it does is to give 2 strings the value from a list of strings. The list contains 52 strings h2, h3, h4, h5 etc. Now if I wish to display the image of a certain card i have these long switches:

```
switch (whatIsTheFirstCard)
        {

                //Hearts
            case "h2":
                Card1Picture.Image = Resource1.h2;
                break;
            case "h3":
                Card1Picture.Image = Resource1.h3;
                break;
            case "h4":
                Card1Picture.Image = Resource1.h4;
                break;
```

etc etc for all the cards. Is there any way to add the images directly to a list and then just call that list instead? The way it is now requires me to copy and paste the switch for each card i wish to display. Needless to say I would rather just have a list that can keep all my bitmap cards.

```
  private void FlopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theCards.DealTheFlop();
        FlopCard1.Image = thebitmapgoeshere;

    }
```

I do not know the syntax for adding bitmaps to a list and then call them from that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the exact same identifiers for the cards in code as in the resources, you can get the appropriate resource through a resource manager directly, i.e

```
FlopCard1.Image = (Bitmap)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("h4", Resources.Culture);
```

Internally, this is also exactly what the generated code does.

This way, you don't need a separate list and you can even easily specify different card sets for different cultures.

Comment: Great! This makes things alot easier. Learn something new everyday, eh? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a Dictionary. You can create a Dictionary using

```
Dictionary<string, Bitmap> myCards = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
```

Next you could iterate the folder contents or something and just go (eg.):

```
myCards.Add("h2", "myfolder/h2.bmp");
```

Finally you can use them using:

```
myControl.Image = myCards["h2"];
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
Card1Picture.Image = (Image)Resource1.ResourceManager.GetObject("h1");
```

**Edit:**
Sorry I didn't see Georg's answer :/